# Rfc2898DeriveBytes returns encrypted key?

Tags: c#, .net

While reading posts for encryption and decryption in C#, I understand that AES algorithm need a key. I found that we can generate key using the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class. Although I can't understand if the derived key is encrypted or not.

If the key is not encrypted i must hashed it before store it in windows registry?

Comment: Please refer this before asking a Query  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, it's not encrypted. It's *cryptographically hashed*. *Encrypted* keys can be retrieved. Strong hashes can't

Comment: So i can store this key in windows registry or i must do somethink else before store it?

Comment: No, you don't store it anywhere. When the user enters the password, you use the class to generate a new key and use it to decrypt whatever you want to decrypt. I suspect you want to do something completely different and think that `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is the answer ?

Comment: I want to encrypt some data in the database and via my application to decrypt those passwords. So, I need a derived key for AES encryption and decryption, Am i correct?

Comment: Are you sure you want to read passwords back from the database? You do understand that doing so is not required to validate that a user typed their password correctly, right? But assuming you do have to read them, can any user read them, or does such a user require a password of some sort?

Comment: Yes I know... I want to make this program for 5 users only and the database is in the local network but i want to have the data encrypted in database!

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph My concept is that I store the encrypted passwords (via AES) in database and the generated key (via rfc2898DeviredBytes class) in windows registry in the pc which use my application. So only the users that use my application can decrypt the encrypted passwords (from database).

Comment: @PanagiotisVangelatos Well, it is only five users, just make them aware that their password is not secure by design. Or make the password handling secure by not storing them in a retrievable (encrypted) fashion. Secure vs insecure, that is the decision you must make.

Comment: Those passwords that i want to store in database  is not personal passwords or credit numbers or something very sensitive information. So is good way to store the key in windows registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rfc2898DeriveBytes doesn't encrypt the password, it creates a strong hash from it that can be used as the key to AES encryption.

By using a salt and hashing a few thousand times it ensures the resulting keys are almost random and can't be guessed, even if the original password is very weak.